# Как прописать игнорирование повторяющихся значений?

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
 public static void Registration(string chatId, string username)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=RegistrationOfUsers; Integrated Security=True";

        string sqlExpression = String.Format($"INSERT INTO RegUsers (ChatId, Username) VALUES ('{0}', {1})", chatId, username);

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlExpression, connection);
            int number = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
           // Console.WriteLine("Добавлено объектов: {0}", number);
        }
    }
```

Ошибка следующая:

```
ERROR: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Нарушено "PK_RegUsers" ограничения PRIMARY KEY. Не удается вставить повторяющийся ключ в объект "dbo.RegUsers". Повторяющееся значение ключа: (0).
Выполнение данной инструкции было прервано.
```

Вот мне и нужно как-то игнор прописать, чтобы просто в бд не добавлялись одинаковые записи.

Comment: Измените запрос на добавление по [этому](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971680/sql-server-insert-if-not-exists) примеру.

Comment: Просто используйте оператор `MERGE` вместо `INSERT`.